# Could not obtain transform from /gps to base_link

Tags: ros, gps, base-link, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After rosrun ekf_localization_node and navsat_transform_node, I got warning like this:
[ WARN] [1494926574.013925839]: Could not obtain transform from /gps to base_link. Error was Invalid argument "/gps" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame in tf2 frame_ids cannot start with a '/' like:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261849/could-not-obtain-transform-from-/gps-to-base_link/) by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means you probably haven't defined the `gps` link in your URDF. The `gps` link should be a link defined on your robot at the location where your GPS is mounted. Make the joint from the `gps` link to its parent link a fixed joint, and the transform should then be available to `navsat_transform_node`.

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on 2017-05-17**:
Well, it sounds reasonable, but I don't know how and where to define that. Would you mind showing me the detail ? I'm new to navsat_transform_node, thank you so much!

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-17**:
Just add a link in your URDF file called `gps`. Will give you the details when I can access a PC in an hour or so.

**Comment by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on 2017-05-17**:
So nice of you. You mean add context like " gps_frame_id : gps " in ekf_template.yaml?

**Comment by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) on 2017-05-17**:
Add this to your URDF file:

```
<link name="gps"/>

<joint name="gps_to_base_link" type="fixed">
<parent link="base_link"/>
<child link="gps"/>
<origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</joint>
```

**Comment by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on 2017-05-18**:
Thank you so much